# Error message when running coxme model with split data

Tags: survival, cox-model, proportional-hazards

I'm trying to model latency to eat in subjects that were each given a treatment and control test three times (so there are six observations per individual, N = 24).

My model violates the proportional hazards assumption (PHA) and running two separate models, one with time to event </= 30 and one with time to event > 30 </= 600 (the max time subjects were given, so includes censored data), showed that the effect of treatment was different in these two models and the PHA was no longer violated.

I thought I would be able to solve this problem with the example given [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) in section 4.1. I ran their example which worked fine, but when I tried it on my own data I got an error message:

```
Error in coxme.fit(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights, :
No starting estimate was successful
```

My code looks as follows:

```
split <- survSplit(Surv(Latency, Status) ~ ., data=data, cut=30,
                  episode= "tgroup") # (it said "id" was already assigned)

mst <- coxme(Surv(Latency, Status) ~ TrialType:strata(tgroup)+Age+strata(TrialSet)+(1|subjectID), data = split)
```

TrialType is the treatment factor with two levels (control/treatment) and TrialSet is a factor with three levels (first/second/third). I stratified by it as it, as well as TrialType, violated the PHA.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67547119/no-starting-estimate-was-successful-error-with-coxme-upon-data-subsetting) previous question but it doesn't seem to be the problem - there are no redundant levels.

Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong?